# Is there a closed form expression for the Taylor series of (1- a X - b Y - c XY )^ (-1)?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Is there a closed form expression for the Taylor series of
f(X , Y ) = (1- a X - b Y - c XY )^ (-1) ?

a, b and c are constants
X and Y are

thank you

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $z=aX=bY-cXY$, but you should know Maclaurin series for $\frac1{1-z}$.

Comment: thank you friend

i know (1-aX-bY-cXY)^(-1) = Sum (aX+bY+cXY)^(n)

Comment: but it is not enough, I need more explicit and accurate with respect to X and Y.